# Centred the View but don't getting the full input width

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

Trying to build sign in page but the input width I am not getting. It is the width of button. The width 100% is not waking on inputs. Any idea

```
return (
    <View style={{
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }}>
      <Card>
        <Input
          placeholder="Email"
          value={username}
          onChangeText={setUsername}
        />
        <Input
          placeholder="Password"
          secureTextEntry={true}
          value={password}
          onChangeText={setPassword}
        />
        <Button
          title="Sign in"
          onPress={() => signin({ username, password })}
        />
      </Card>

    </View>
  );
```

[image]

Also I am using

```
import { Card, Button, Text, Input } from "react-native-elements";
```

Comment: Share your styles for the inputs. 
Set your view to 100% as that is the parent.  Once the parent container has a set width then you can assign a width of 100% to the inputs and buttons.

Comment: Can you share the styles and a pic of how it looks and how it should look? Remember that ideally, we want to solve it using flexbox.

Comment: Added the photo and it should be in center and have proper user input space.

Comment: @Aleksandar Zoric I used width: 300, and width:100% thinking this should work in input. And haven't used any other. just needed width where user can input data.

Comment: And I am using react-native-elements lib.

Comment: Share your styles where you set the width. You have flex applied to the View, what are the styles for the Card?